# Is it possible to disable error reporting only for part of your script?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging

The PHP documentation [reads](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (emphasis mine):

> The error_reporting() function sets the error_reporting directive at
>   runtime. PHP has many levels of errors, **using this function sets that
>   level for the duration (runtime) of your script.** If the optional level
>   is not set, error_reporting() will just return the current error
>   reporting level.

Does that mean that the level of error reporting can only be set *once* in a PHP script, and not changed afterwards? For instance, is it possible to do this:

```
error_reporting(0);

try {
  errorSilently();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Do nothing
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
  errorLOUDLY();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Do nothing
}
```

Note that I wrote a `// Do nothing` because it seems that if an error is thrown, Apache writes it to its `error_log` any way, if it's caught or not. What I want to do is disable that behaviour, and not write to the error log.

Comment: You can also suppress certain errors by prefixing with `@` - e.g. `if(!@mail( ... )) { ... }` ... sets my teeth on edge slightly but, there you go : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @CD001 - Thanks for the reminder about this! It's a much better solution in my situation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can change the error reporting level at any time during your program's runtime, and it will stay at that new level until you change it again. You *can* "silence" only specific parts. Note that `error_reporting()` returns the *old* level, specifically so you can do things like:

```
$previous = error_reporting(0);

something_which_produces_warnings_which_can_safely_be_ignored();

error_reporting($previous);
```

To also temporarily disable error *logging* you may have to `ini_set('log_errors', false)`.

And no, `try..catch` has nothing to do with *error reporting*. Those are separate mechanisms. `error_reporting` influences errors triggered by [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/trigger_error); `try..catch` is a mechanism for handling exceptions thrown via `throw`.

Comment: To OP: And if you are talking about FATAL errors, you cannot catch them. Fatal is Fatal, no way round that

Comment: Thank you. Also for that last paragraph, I was mixing things up. I thought that an error I was getting was coming from an Exception, but it was actually a PHP error - which makes more sense.